# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when bean is defined in XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans, code-injection

I am trying to refer to a bean that's defined in an XML file using the @Resource annotation, but I keep getting a `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` exception.

Here are the files:

**Employee.java:**

```
public class Employee {
   private String name;
   private int age;

   //getter and setter methods
}
```

**EmployeeManager.java:**

```
@Service("employeeManager")
public class EmployeeManager {

   @Resource(name="employeeList")
   private List<Employee> employeeList;

   //other methods here
}
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
    
    <bean id="employeeList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
               <ref bean="bob" />
               <ref bean="sally" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="bob" class="Employee">
        <property name="name" value="Bob"/>
        <property name="age" value="40"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sally" class="Employee">                    
        <property name="name" value="Sally"/>
        <property name="age" value="44"/>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

Ideally, I would like the employeeList variable in EmployeeManager.java to be injected with a List containing Employee objects of bob and sally. When I run my application, I get the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'employeeManager': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'employeeList' available
```

I'm not sure if I missed something, or if my setup is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for declaring beans in applicationContex.xml is wrong. The syntax for declaring the BEAN is

Syntax:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="<beanReferenceName>" class="fullyQualifiedName of the class"/>
</beans>
```

Egg:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="transferService" class="com.acme.TransferServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```

Add fully qualified name of the Employee class in your applicationContext.xml